# Is it illegal to overload methods with multiple parameter lists?

Tags: scala, overloading

Trying to define two methods named `foo`, one taking two parameter lists, and the other one only having one. Does not seem to work:

```
object Bar { 
  def foo(a: Int)(b: Int): Int = a+b
  def foo(a: Int): Int = foo(a)(0)
 }
error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method foo in object Bar of type (a: Int)Int
and  method foo in object Bar of type (a: Int)(b: Int)Int
match argument types (Int)
      def foo(a: Int): Int = foo(a)(0)
                             ^
```

??? no, they don't ...

Comment: `Bar.foo(1)` would invoke which of the two?

Comment: See also: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2383

Comment: @pedrofurla it would invoke the one with the single parameter list, obviously.

Comment: @Dima The link is at the top of the page.

Comment: @m-z Sorry ... don't know how I missed that

Comment: @Dima, I was point to the ambiguity.

Comment: @pedrofurla where's the ambiguity? I don't see it

Answer (score 4):

Instead of manually overloading your function you could just as easily define a default parameter. As the error message already tells you, the reference is ambiguous, so it's disallowed.

Here's your function with a default parameter:

```
def foo(a: Int)(b: Int = 0): Int = a+b
```

Comment: I know that :) It's not quite the same though, because, with the default parameter, I'd still have to call it like `foo(a)()`, and what I want is just `foo(a)`.